# Google Maps API v3 - How to specify "VehicleType"

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm having some difficulties to specify Vehicle Type in my request. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#VehicleType), it should look like something like this:

```
var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    TransitDetails: google.maps.TransitLine.TransitVehicle.VehicleType.BUS
};
```

But the folowing error shows up every time:

```
TypeError: google.maps.TransitLine is undefined
```

I think there's something wrong with my TransitDetails path.. but I can't figure out what exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `TransitDetails`-option for a `directionsRequest`.

There is only a `TransitOptions`-option where you can define `departureTime` and `arrivalTime` . The `vehicleType` is a part of the `directionsResponse` and is a simple string(e.g. `BUS`)

Comment: So is there any way I can set my vehicleType to "BUS", because I'd like to get the driving duration from A to B, but with BUS (not with car).

Comment: currently there is no such option